# ¿Como quitar caracter extraño de ventana confirm de javascript?

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo una ventana de confirmación mediante javascript con el siguiente mensaje "¿Estas seguro que desea enviar la factura?", pero cuando se muestra en pantalla, visualizo un carácter especial y no se como quitarlo "Â¿Estas seguro de enviar la factura electronica?"

Adjunto el codigo:

```js
var opcion = confirm("¿Estas seguro de enviar la factura electronica?");

  if(opcion == true){
    console.log("Si");  
  } else{
    console.log("No");
  }
```

Comment: Que navegador utilizas? No veo el caracter.

Comment: Haz definido <meta charset="utf-8"> en el head de tu documento? Aunque es extraño por que ese carácter aparece justo antes de ¿ y ahí no tienes nada con tildes ni ñ, al ejecutar en el snippet de SOes no aparece

Comment: Yo utilizo google chrome, exacto yo tambien estoy corriendo mi codigo snippet y tampoco me aparece. Puedes ver este caracter (Â)? de hecho ya revise y el charset y aparece como iso-8859-1

Comment: Puede ser por eso, cambialo a utf-8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes dos opciones:

1. Comprobar que tengas definido como te han dicho el lenguaje utf8, con la instrucción `<meta charset="utf-8">`
2. Usar los caracteres de escape de `javascript`, cambiando tu instrucción por esta otra `var opcion = confirm("\u00BF Estas seguro de enviar la factura electronica?");`

Answer (score 0):

"`Â¿`" es la la interpretación `latin-1` del carácter `UTF-8` "`¿`". Tendrías problemas similares con las tildes si las hubieses añadido (`Estás` y `electrónica`). Como otros han indicado, lo solucionarás añadiendo el meta: `<meta charset="utf-8">` en el `<head>` de la página.